# Turning promise into an int

Tags: angularjs, protractor

This maybe a silly question however I am having troubles finding the answer I need for this.  I have a test that counts the repeater.  I'd like to return the count variable so I may pass it over to another test to be used in a for loop.

What I've tried:

```js
this.countsInitialBookings = function() {
  var j = 0;
  browser.driver.sleep(3000);
  bookingLists = element.all(by.repeater('booking in bookingsCtrl.bookings'));
  bookingLists.count().then(function(count) {
    //have also tried making bookingCount global and setting value to 0   
    var bookingCount = count;
  });
  return bookingCount;
};
```

This is what spits outStarted

```
.{ closure_uid_966269928: 651,
  flow_: 
   { events_: {},
     closure_uid_966269928: 1,
     activeFrame_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_966269928: 642,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     schedulingFrame_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_966269928: 642,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     eventLoopTask_: null,
     hold_: 
      { _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 99601735,
        _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
        _repeat: true },
     yieldCount_: 1 },
  stack_: null,
  parent_: 
   { closure_uid_966269928: 649,
     flow_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_966269928: 1,
        activeFrame_: [Object],
        schedulingFrame_: [Object],
        shutdownTask_: null,
        eventLoopTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        yieldCount_: 1 },
     stack_: null,
     parent_: 
      { closure_uid_966269928: 647,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [Object],
        callbacks_: [Object],
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: true,
        pendingNotifications_: false,
        value_: undefined },
     callbacks_: [ [Object] ],
     state_: 'pending',
     handled_: true,
     pendingNotifications_: false,
     value_: undefined },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  pendingNotifications_: false,
  value_: undefined }
.


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 17.516 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You can't get the integer out of the promise until after it has resolved, which will be long after the return statement has executed. In other words, what you are trying to do is impossible. Solve the problem another way.

Comment: @Kevin did i read somewhere you can force a resolve?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, or how it relates to your problem. You can take a rejected promise chain and make it resolve instead, and you can make a promise that is immediately resolved (though it will still be asynchronous, so your return will still fail) but you still won't be able to return the end value from the outer function.

Comment: @Kevin I also tried a for loop which which i put var j inside, did a j++, this is an int not sure why that doesn't return either.

Comment: Inside where? the .then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.count()` is asynchronous, it is not going to be possible to return the integer from `countsInitialBookings`. Instead, you should return the promise, then you can use the promise later to get the value.

```
this.countsInitialBookings = function() {
  var j = 0;
  browser.driver.sleep(3000);
  bookingLists = element.all(by.repeater('booking in bookingsCtrl.bookings'));
  return bookingLists.count()
};
```

later on...

```
this.countsInitialBookings().then(function (count) {
    console.log(count);
});
// do not attempt to get `count` out here, it's simply not possible. 
// It will only be accessible inside the above callback.
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, this promise stuff can be a bit confusing and is taking some time to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Kevin B's answer...

You are returning a " Promise Skeleton " object.  It is important to manage your promise chains in a way that ensures you are 1.) returning async calls 2.) returning any values you need 3.) and chaining the promises in the correct place.

Though I agree with Kevin's answer, making bookingcount global, or changing its scope, may lead to another solution.